# Generate C# code with Roslyn and .NET Core

Tags: c#, roslyn, .net-core

Is there a way to generate C# code using Roslyn with .NET Core. I've tried using the SyntaxFactory from the package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp. The problem I'm currently stuck with is getting proper formatted code as text from it.

All the samples I've seen so far use something like

```
var ws = new CustomWorkspace();
ws.Options.WithChangedOption (CSharpFormattingOptions.IndentBraces, true);
var code = Formatter.Format (item, ws);
```

The problem here is, that they all use the package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces which isn't compatible with .NET Core at the moment. Are there any alternative routes or workarounds for using Roslyn as a code generator with .NET Core?

Comment: Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces 1.3.2 supports `netstandard1.3`, so it should be compatible with .Net Core.

Comment: The problem is with a dependency, not Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces directly - "The dependency Microsoft.Composition 1.0.27 does not support framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0."

Comment: Microsoft.Composition is a PCL, so you should be able to use in .Net Core if you add `"imports": "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"` to your project.json.

Comment: Works now, haven't realized that PCLs are not supported out of the box. Can you write it up as an answer so I can accept the answer and reward you for your help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces` 1.3.2 supports `netstandard1.3`, so it should be compatible with .Net Core. But it depends on `Microsoft.Composition` 1.0.27, which only supports `portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81`. This framework moniker is compatible with .Net Core, but only if you import it in your project.json.

That means that to make this work, the relevant sections of your project.json should look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces": "1.3.2"
},
"frameworks": {
  "netcoreapp1.0": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "type": "platform",
        "version": "1.0.0"
      }
    },
    "imports": "portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81"
  }
}
```