# Code generation with .Net Standard

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I have a [little library](https://github.com/Pzixel/WcfRestClient) which relies hugely on Emitting classes and methods.

I want to migrate it to .Net Standard because it doesn't use any unmanaged things so can be easily running on whatever OS. But when I ran Portability checker on my solution, it showed that everything is OK with my `Expression` generator part, but it is whining on `Emit` usages.

Here is analysis for `net452`,`netstandard1.6` and `netstandard2.0`.

[image]

My question is if there is some modern and recommended way to generate classes at runtime which is supported by .Net Standard or I can just forget about porting my library to it?

Comment: That would be Roslyn, the recommended way to generate classes in C# 6 and above. C# scripting uses it to do just that, generate and run classes from the script text

Comment: This could be considered a [duplicate of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39197663/generate-c-sharp-code-with-roslyn-and-net-core)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It seems that this functionality [is under construction](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5561) so Rosylin cannot generate code in build time atm.

Comment: Beware that while *generating* classes at runtime may be done, *loading* those dynamically generated classes is fundamentally incompatible with some of the platforms that do support .NET Standard. Realistically, if you're serious about .NET Standard, I don't see any option but to radically re-think your entire project, sorry. Just .NET Core could perhaps be possible though, if that might be good enough for you.

Comment: @hvd I'm not affraid of thinking :) For example, I really wasn't thinking about Rosylin usage although now I see that required functionallity is not ready yet. You can examine link below, `Test` section of solution, there is sample usages. You just cannot do such things with Rosylin currently.

Comment: `Emit` is not supported on Xamarin.iOS and that's probably why it does not list in .NET Standard. You will have to check what else can be used, as there is at least a C# IDE on iOS which shows the feasibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found that nowadays in `.Net Standard` we have expression trees to generate standalone delegates and old fashioned `Emit` (available with `System.Reflection.Emit` and `System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight` namespaces) for the rest. Unfortunly, we lost bridge between the former and the latter (I mean `LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod`, [see question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520319/alternatives-of-compiletomethod-in-net-standard)).

So generaly there is almost same code generation power as in full desktop `.Net` until you don't need to generate types at runtime (implement some interface on the fly, for example). In this case you are forced to emit IL manually.

Comment: I'm working on a Roslyn-based solution that works for all frameworks and in compile-time. It's even more powerful. So, if you have to generate expressions just use them. For class-generation it's easier to take Roslyn API and create a plugin that generates them during build. See [this project (not mine, i'm just using it)](https://github.com/AArnott/CodeGeneration.Roslyn) for more details.