# Alternatives of CompileToMethod in .Net Standard

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm now porting some library that uses expressions to `.Net Core` application and encountered a problem that all my logic is based on `LambdaExpression.CompileToMethod` which is simply missing in. Here is sample code:

```
public static MethodInfo CompileToInstanceMethod(this LambdaExpression expression, TypeBuilder tb, string methodName, MethodAttributes attributes)
{
    ...

    var method = tb.DefineMethod($"<{proxy.Name}>__StaticProxy", MethodAttributes.Private | MethodAttributes.Static, proxy.ReturnType, paramTypes);
    expression.CompileToMethod(method);

    ...
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite it somehow to make it possible to generate methods using Expressions? I already can do it with `Emit` but it's quite complex and i'd like to avoid it in favor of high-level Expressions.

I tried to use `var method = expression.Compile().GetMethodInfo();` but in this case I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to import a global method or
>   field from a different module.

I know that I can emit IL manually, but I need exactly convert `Expression` -> to `MethodInfo` binded to specific `TypeBuilder` instead of building myself `DynamicMethod` on it.

Comment: Wow, trying to answer this question I just found out that .Net core has lacking documentation and no easy way to find out what was replaced by what... Best of luck into that port...

Comment: @LucasCorsaletti I think it's very hard to provide such a documentation, because I guess even .net core team doesn't know what was replaced by what :) Anyway, thank you for a try

Comment: Interesting, I'm watching this question. Just tried to create class/instance methods with Linq.Expressions and old .NET 4.5 recently. Dynamic methods could be created as instance methods, with respect to visibility attributes, but required Reflection.Emit. Building it with Linq.Expressions was much more readable, but it could not be used as an instance method. However, I could shamelessly access internals and privates, making the same functionality possible as with an instance method. I'm just a beginner with runtime code generation...

Comment: @ErikHart I have a workaround for instance methos, [see link](https://github.com/Pzixel/WcfRestClient/blob/master/WcfRestClient.Core/Helpers/XLambdaExpression.cs). So, code piece above is from this workaround which stopped to work with migration to .Net Core :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Attempting to get LambdaCompiler working on .NET Core

Building on Michal Komorowski's answer, I decided to give porting `LambdaCompiler` to .NET Core a try. You can find my effort [here](https://github.com/perlun/LambdaCompiler) (GitHub link). The fact that the class is spread over multiple files is honestly one of the smallest problems here. A much bigger problem is that it relies on internal parts in the .NET Core codebase.

Quoting myself from the GitHub repo above:

> Unfortunately, it is non-trivial because of (at least) the following issues:
>
> - AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly is unavailable in .NET Core - AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly replaces is. This SO answer describes how it can be used.
> - Assembly.DefineVersionInfoResource is unavailable.
> - Reliance on internal methods and properties, for example BlockExpression.ExpressionCount, BlockExpression.GetExpression, BinaryExpression.IsLiftedLogical etc.
>
> For the reasons given above, an attempt to make this work as a standalone package is quite unfruitful in nature. The only realistic way to get this working would be to include it in .NET Core proper.
>
> This, however, is problematic for other reasons. I believe the licensing is one of the stumbling stones here. Some of this code was probably written as part of the DLR effort, which it itself Apache-licensed. As soon as you have contributions from 3rd party contributors in the code base, relicensing it (to MIT, like the rest of the .NET Core codebase) becomes more or less impossible.

#### Other options

I think your best bet at the moment, depending on the use case, is one of these two:

- Use the [DLR (Dynamic Language Runtime)](https://github.com/IronLanguages/dlr), available from NuGet (Apache 2.0-licensed). This is the runtime that empowers [IronPython](https://ironpython.net/), which is to the best of my knowledge the only actively maintained DLR-powered language out there. (Both IronRuby and IronJS seems to be effectively abandoned.) The DLR lets you define lambda expressions using `Microsoft.Scripting.Ast.LambdaBuilder`; this doesn't seem to be directly used by IronPython though. There is also the `Microsoft.Scripting.Interpreter.LightCompiler` class which seems to be quite interesting.

  The DLR unfortunately seems to be quite poorly documented. I think there is a wiki being referred to by [the CodePlex site](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=dlr), but it's offline (can probably be accessed by downloading the archive on CodePlex though).
- Use Roslyn to compile the (dynamic) code for you. This probably has a bit of a learning curve as well; I am myself not very familiar with it yet unfortunately.

  This seems to have quite a lot of curated links, tutorials etc: https://github.com/ironcev/awesome-roslyn. I would recommend this as a starting point. If you're specifically interested in building methods dynamically, these also seem worth reading:

  - https://gunnarpeipman.com/using-roslyn-to-build-object-to-object-mapper/
  - http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/compiling-c-sharp-code-into-memory-and-executing-it-with-roslyn

  Here are some other general Roslyn reading links. Most of these links are however focused on *analyzing* C# code here (which is one of the use cases for Roslyn), but Roslyn can be used to *generate* IL code (i.e. "compile") C# code as well.

  - The .NET Compiler Platform SDK: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/
  - Get started with syntax analysis: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/get-started/syntax-analysis
  - Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix

There is also the third option, which is probably uninteresting for most of us:

- Use [System.Reflection.Emit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Emit/) directly, to generate the IL instructions. This is the approach used by e.g. the [F# compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp).

Answer (score 7):

It is not an ideal solution but it is worth considering if you don't want to write everything from the scratch:

1. If you look on `CompileToMethod` implementation, you will see that under the hood it uses internal `LambdaCompiler` class.
2. If you dig even deeper, you willl see that `LambdaCompiler` uses `System.Reflection.Emit` to convert lambdas into `MethodInfo`.
3. `System.Reflection.Emit` is supported by .NET Core.
4. Taking this into account, my proposition is to try to reuse the `LambdaCompiler` source code. You can find it [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Compiler/LambdaCompiler.cs).

The biggest problem with this solution is that:

1. `LambdaCompiler` is spread among many files so it may be cumbersome to find what is needed to compile it.
2. `LambdaCompiler` may use some API which is not supported by .NET Core at all.

A few additional comments:

1. If you want to check which API is supported by which platform use [.NET API Catalog](https://apisof.net/).
2. If you want to see differences between .NET standard versions use [this](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/tree/master/docs/versions) site.

Comment: I decompiled `CompileToMethod` before asking the question, however I stopped when found out that `LambdaCompiler` is internal. However, now I got an idea that we can call some internal methods via reflection. *No, velociraptor, don't eat me ([you got the joke](https://xkcd.com/292/)).* I'l make some research and come back with results and mark this an answer if no one else want to help us.

Comment: So I'm here. For unknown reason `.Net Standard` is missing constructor `LambdaCompiler(AnalyzedTree tree, LambdaExpression lambda, MethodBuilder method)`. There is no reason for not providing it, because `MethodBuilder` is used in another overload, so every required assembly is referenced. I think I should post a question on some repository (corefx?). Currently I'd like to create a pull request fixing this problem but not sure about repo.

Comment: After looking on `corefx` sources I found that it's done intentionally with `FEATURE_COMPILE_TO_METHODBUILDER` flag. Don't know why, however.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue when porting some code to netstandard. My solution was to compile the lambda to a Func using the Compile method, store the Func in a static field that I added to my dynamic type, then in my dynamic method I simply load and call the Func from that static field. This allows me to create the lambda using the LINQ Expression APIs instead of reflection emit (which would have been painful), but still have my dynamic type implement an interface (which was another requirement for my scenario).

Feels like a bit of a hack, but it works, and is probably easier than trying to recreate the CompileToMethod functionality via LambdaCompiler.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I am author of the library.

I have created Expression Compiler, which has similar API to that of Linq Expressions, with slight changes. https://github.com/yantrajs/yantra/wiki/Expression-Compiler

```
var a = YExpression.Parameter(typeof(int));
var b = YExpression.Parameter(typeof(int));

var exp = YExpression.Lambda<Func<int,int,int>>("add",
            YExpression.Binary(a, YOperator.Add, b),
            new YParameterExpression[] { a, b });

var fx = exp.CompileToStaticMethod(methodBuilder);

Assert.AreEqual(1, fx(1, 0));
Assert.AreEqual(3, fx(1, 2));
```

This library is part of JavaScript compiler we have created. We are actively developing it and we have added features of generators and async/await in JavaScript, so Instead of using Expression Compiler, you can create debuggable JavaScript code and run C# code easily into it.